# Multistore- more stores with 1 language file?

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, language, multicurrency

We have a multistore with seperate shops for the US, UK, Australia and Switzerland because of the Google restrictions.

Now we have to translate all the shops sepperate. Is it possible to have for example that US, UK, Australian shop to use one content language file but keeps it's own currency ?

So we only have to translate 1 time to English and all the shops using English are done too ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible but not exactly in a way you've described (at least with the information you've provided).

You can configure your instance **base currency** on website scope level (the displayed currency on store scope which can be converted from base currency) and language on store view scope. The saving of the price depends whether you'll want separate prices for each website or converted through currency rate to target currency.

[You can learn more about scopes here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362041/in-depth-explanation-of-magentos-store-store-view-website-layers)

Translation files are located in following locations:

`MAGENTO_ROOT/app/locale/en_US/*.csv`

the en_US stands for:

- en - english language code [List of ISO 639-1 codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes)
- US - country - if there's a variation of the language. examples: de_DE, de_AT, de_CH, en_GB, en_US, etc.

Login to your Magento admin panel and proceed to Configuration  > General.

There's a **Locale** setting dropdown where you can choose your store language. As you can see there's a list of languages and sometimes there're multiple entries for one language i.e. English (United States) and English (Australia). If you decide to use one translation for all variations then you simply switch to default scope and set the option on default scope level. If you'd like to have a different languages then you switch the scope in the upper left side of the screen to website/store - depending on your need, choose your setting and press **Save Config** button in the upper right side of screen.

Now switch the scope to **Default** and go to Configuration > General > Currency Setup.

When you're on Default or Website scope you can see an option to change **Base Currency**. This is the currency that will be used when saving products in website scope and converting it to the **Displayed Currency** in store scope which you can find in a field below.

If there's anything unclear let me know in the comment and I'll update my answer.

### Edit with information about product/category attribute translations.

Description for products and categories are attributes saved in a database, not in files (unless you've got some customization done).

As default when you create a new website/store and enable products for it, it will fall back to Default Scope value. This can be used as an advantage for your need - it allows to **not enter** new translations for websites/stores in same language as the default store and mark the checkbox called "Use Default" next to every attribute field in admin that has scope setup as website/store and not global. As long as I understand you correctly you'd setup the default store locale to english and translate only stores that are in different language.

Comment: We have done that, but I am talking about translations of the product descriptions. It would be nice if for example the US store could use the product and category descriptions of the English website.

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Comment: Problem is the main language is Dutch 

Comment: Then switch your default language to english, in dutch store untick use default value and then update default values with english language. Eventually you could create a module that would use observer and update category/product in specific scope with values from specific store.